# LDAP User Access to WSO2 Governance Registry Store / Publisher

Tags: authentication, wso2, store, publisher, governance-registry

We managed to setup LDAP as a secondary User Store in the WSO2 Governance Registry Management Console 5.3.0 (Carbon). We see the Users/Roles were loaded correctly and we can access Management Console (Carbon) with those users.

However despite of the LDAP users having "Internal/store" permission, they cannot access/sign in to WSO2 Governance Center - STORE. The error on the Sign In page is: "Insufficient priveleages to access the Store application."

Comment: In your CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml, inside the AuthorizationManager Block have you set the GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled property to true?  the default is false and has caused this issue for me before.

Comment: thanks so much for the hint, however my problem was that I did not specify the domain name in front of the username

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem just with putting the domain name of the User Store and forward slash in front of the LDAP username: <domain_name>/<user_name>

When the username is specified without the domain name, the Store application gives misleading error: "Insufficient priveleages to access the Store application." I think it should respond with different error, for example: "The provided username and password combination is incorrect."